# Why does `std::unary_function` still compile in c++17?

Tags: c++, g++, c++17

The [`std::unary_function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/unary_function) feature was deprecated in c++11 and deleted in c++17. But with the c++17 compiler flag, this code still compiles:

```
struct less_than_7 : std::unary_function<int, bool>
{
    bool operator()(int i) const { return i < 7; }
};
```

Built with `g++ -std=c++17 -O0 -Wall -pedantic main.cpp` [here.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbcc9db8625630d1)

Is a feature deletion optional for a compiler to implement?

Comment: Report it as a bug - it's easy to fix, and an important diagnostic for your UB code.

Comment: two possible answers: (1) the libstdc++ maintainers haven't got around to removing it yet, or (2) they left it there for backwards compatibility for people compiling with C++03/11/14.

Comment: I'm finding that it does not compile on Mac OS 11.6. I have a project that includes Boost, which uses unary_function. The thing won't build, because unary_function is undefined. Oddly, however, I'm specifying C++14 in my CMake file and in the Clang invocation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's no longer part of the C++17 standard its inclusion in one of your source code files falls into the same category as code that introduces things into `std`.

In other words, the program behaviour is *undefined*.

The program working is a manifestation of that undefined behaviour. And perhaps your implementation *defines* that undefined behaviour. But even so, your code is not portable C++17.

Comment: Still though, that's letting the compiler off easy isn't it?

Comment: @kabanus: Possibly yes. All the C++ standard library writers need to do is to test __cplusplus. Quite an intrusive addition though.

Comment: No error, no warning, no indication that this is bad at all ... This doesn't seem like a good behaviour for the compiler to have.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox nothing to do with the compiler, its a fault of the standard library implementation (libstdc++ presumably)

Answer (score 2):

While it's nice to have standards, and multiple versions of those standards, the reality is that different toolchains have different levels of compliance.

This may involve delays implementing new features, delays implementing changes, or delays removing things.

This is simply a case of the latter.

VS 2019 has removed `std::unary_function`, but neither libstdc++ nor libc++ has yet. That's just how it is!

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to find the appropriate wording, but implementations do have a lot of leeway in adding extra names to `std`. That's a major reason why you can't - the two names might clash.

In particular, the existing implementation can have helper classes in `std`. Thus `std::unary_function` might have become merely a helper template for this particular implementation.